# Objective-C class property type not exposed to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I got a Swift Project with an Objective-C library linked via CocoaPods. It works fine, I can call all methods etc. Also my Bridging-Header is existing and working.

But I got a problem with some properties of my Objective-C classes.

Here is my class:

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "OAIObject.h"

#import "OAILayerTreeGroupAllOf.h"
#import "OAILayerTreeItem.h"
@protocol OAILayerTreeGroupAllOf;
@class OAILayerTreeGroupAllOf;
@protocol OAILayerTreeItem;
@class OAILayerTreeItem;



@protocol OAILayerTreeGroup
@end

@interface OAILayerTreeGroup : OAILayerTreeItem


@property(nonatomic) NSArray<OAILayerTreeItem>* children;

@end
```

I can create this object from Swift code.
But if I try to access the children I get the type "Any", so I can't access the property children.

[image]

Is there a way to access the property type of my Objective-C class?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that your Objective-C generics declaration does not contain a `*`.

Can you try to change your property declaration to

```
@property(nonatomic) NSArray<OAILayerTreeItem *> *children;
```

Your `NSArray` instance contains objects that are of type `OAILayerTreeItem`, that's why you need the `*`.

Please note that I was unable to try this.

Comment: It works, I can see my properties. But if I try to iterate with forEach over this array in Swift I get the error "Precondition failed: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type". If I do it my way I can iterate with forEach over the Array but got no type.

Comment: In that case case your `NSArray` so a Swift `Array` before using `forEach`.